# Could not load type ImageResizer.InterceptModule

Tags: imageresizer

ImageResizer is setup and working in our test and development environments, however we can not get it working in our production environment. I have setup the IIS site the same (except for the name etc) and have the same Web.config options (only ImageResizer related things in there).... and no dice. We keep getting the error below. We have already tried re-downloading the files, and we checked the other suggestions. All to no avail.

**.NET Version 4.5.2.**

dll version 4.0.4.934 (we also tried with 4.0.5)... same result.

At the very bottom of the error page, the following displays... which may explain things? .NET 4.5.2 is on the server but it looks like the site is not configured to use it, perhaps?:

**Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load type 'ImageResizer.InterceptModule'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.InterceptModule'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'ImageResizer.InterceptModule'.]
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +12512121
>      System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +76
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load type 'ImageResizer.InterceptModule'.]
>      System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +12425644
>      System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +69
>      System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +62
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +299
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1262
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +133
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'ImageResizer.InterceptModule'.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618980
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458597

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection,ImageResizer" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <resizer>
        <!-- Unless you (a) use Integrated mode, or (b) map all requests to ASP.NET, 
        you'll need to add .ashx to your image URLs: image.jpg.ashx?width=200&height=20 -->
        <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true" />
        <diskcache dir="/cache" />
        <plugins>
            <add name="DiskCache" />
            <!-- <add name="PrettyGifs" /> -->
            <!-- <add name="SimpleFilters" /> -->
            <!-- <add name="S3Reader" /> -->
        </plugins>
    </resizer>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <!-- This is for IIS7/8 Classic Mode and Cassini-->
            <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules>
            <!-- This is for IIS7/8 Integrated mode -->
            <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Additional Error Info...

> Could not load file or assembly 'ImageResizer' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ImageResizer' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'ImageResizer' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: Which version of .NET is enabled for the ASP.NET site?

Comment: Also, please show the associated web.config element. Did you specify the assembly name?

Comment: Post updated with .Net version and Web.config.

Comment: Try specifying the assembly name: ImageResizer.InterceptModule, ImageResizer

Comment: Anywhere ImageResizer.InterceptModule appears in the file.

Comment: OK.. that yielded some additional info. The bin folder is a virtual directory and the two dlls are in there.... this is the same exact setup as our test environment. Not sure why it's saying the file is not found...

Comment: You can't make /bin a virtual directory.

Comment: That is odd. It works now that I switched bin to a normal directory in the web root. How on earth does it work in our test environment with the bin setup as a virtual directory???!?!?

Comment: Virtual directories on the same disk get special treatment, I believe. But they are still officially unsupported for /bin

Answer (score 0):

Even though our test environment has the "bin" folder setup as a virtual directory in IIS, this did not work in our production environment. It most likely has to do with the way the drives and site roots and content are setup and stored.

Test VM:

IIS Site Root -> X:\some.site\wwww
"bin" virtual directory -> Y:\bin

Prod VM:

Does not work:

IIS Site Root -> X:\some.site\wwww (which is a symlink to a SAN share)
"bin" virtual directory -> C:\bin

Works:

"bin" is a directory in the site root (on the SAN share)

Thanks Nathanael for the help.

Comment: Since this is the most related question I found about my issue. Can you please explain what shall I do If you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I accidentally changed the directory of the Default Website on IIS to the root folder of one of my projects whose web.config file includes the ImageResizingModule.
I fixed the issue by just changing the physical path of the Default Website on IIS to the wwwroot folder.